# Pandas append multiple dataframes in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Some background**

I have written a *for* loop in which I am trying to append multiple dataframes. In each iteration a new dataframe is created and I want to append that dataframe to existing dataframes.

In  each iteration I am pulling datafrom postgres database

Below is my code

```
temp = my_base_dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = pd.DataFrame()


for index, row in temp.iterrows():
    #Part 1 Get min, max timestamp for each ID
    ID = row['recorded_id']
    min_time = row['min']
    max_time = row['max']

    #Part2 Query redshift with parameters from part 1
    if df.empty:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT key, tag name, description, datetime, tag_value FROM (SELECT tag_value,datetime, data_key, dim_facility_key FROM pub.values_numeric WHERE datetime>= '"+ str(min_time)+"' AND datetime<= '"+ str(max_time)+"' AND key = 72) n INNER JOIN (SELECT name, data_key, description, id FROM pub.data WHERE id = 'CM01') m ON m.key = n.key;", engine)
        df['ID'] = ID
    else:
        df1 = df1.append(df)
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT key, tag name, description, datetime, 
        tag_value FROM (SELECT tag_value,datetime, data_key, dim_facility_key 
        FROM pub.values_numeric WHERE datetime>= '"+ str(min_time)+"' AND 
        datetime<= '"+ str(max_time)+"' AND key = 72) n INNER JOIN (SELECT name, 
        data_key, description, id FROM pub.data WHERE id = 'CM01') m ON m.key = n.key;", engine)
        df['ID'] = ID
df1 = df1.append(df)
len(df1)
```

**The problem**

I have tested the above code and it works fine but I do not feel that it is efficient/robust enough.

Any improvement in the code will be helpful.

I want a more pythonic/efficient way of appending dataframes in a loop

Comment: Depending on the size of the tables you're querying you may be better off querying for data between the global min and max timestamps and then applying filters in pandas afterwards.

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry size of the table is too large. So I am querying separately for each `ID`